# PowerShell script to execute MSI with parameters

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, powershell-3.0

[image]

How to write PowerShell script for attached screenshots? I am trying to run and configure installer via PowrShell.

[image: setup]

Comment: You need to consult the documentation of that setup / application. There is no generally valid way to pass arbitrary values to MSI installers. Including the possibility that their might not be any way at all.

Comment: Thanks for the response !!! I know how to pass value to msi but my issue is how to go to advanced and select "install on local "

Comment: That's my point. You simply can't (let alone some wild stunds using automation APIs, etc.), unless the producer of that MSI (Setup really) has provided a way to do so. You have to contact them and ask to get a definitive answer.

Comment: @Christian.K Windows Installer is designed to enable this. It's certainly possible to create a bad MSI that prevents it from working (accidentally or intentionally), but automated silent configured installs are one of its core capabilities. The hard part is figuring out the names, dealing with badly authored MSIs, and determining any undocumented "business rules" that you need to follow.

Comment: @MichaelUrman Yes Windows Installer enables this _in principle_, but as you say "the hard pard is figuring out the names... and determining .. business rules ..." - that is all I was alluding to with my comment about "ask the author of the installer about this". Posting a question about any other product's installer is not very much answerable in a concrete fashion. However, it is good you could help the OP anyway.

Comment: Did you get this working? Looking for (public, or UPPERCASE) properties used in the dialogs, and properties set in the property table and the list view of features in the dialog you show should give you enough information in most cases to generate a good candidate silent install command. As others have said it all depends on how well-designed the MSI really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee that this will be possible, as it's possible to (incorrectly) author a Windows Installer package in a way that rejects this. But in many cases, it suffices to find the feature names, property names, and property values involved in the settings you wish to control.

Note that to approach 100% correctness, you will have to consider all properties that get set during the normal UI sequence, or consult documentation provided by the author of the package.

#### Feature Selection

You can specify which features will be installed by listing their names in the special properties: [ADDLOCAL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367536), [REMOVE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371194), [ADDSOURCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367538), etc. To find their names, consult documentation, or examine the [Feature table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368585) of the .msi file.

Note that doing this can evade attempts the author might have made to ensure proper selection of features (for some meaning of proper), and it will also set the property [Preselected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370839), which offers the author a way to tweak the behavior in this situation.

#### Configuration

Windows Installer dialog boxes are all defined in the [Dialog table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368286) and [Control table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368044), but the results can also be augmented by the [ControlEvent table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368037) and custom actions. In the common case you can look at the Control table to identify the Property name associated with the values you wish to set. For example, an Edit control with Property value TESTPROP will set the property TESTPROP to whatever you type into its associated edit box. Check boxes cross reference the [CheckBox table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367855) for the value they will set or clear (often simply **1**), etc. Radio button groups cross reference the [RadioButton table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370962) for their values.

Sometimes intermediate values may be set by the controls, and their eventual target properties are then adjusted by a custom action invoked by a Control Event or a sequenced Custom Action.

#### Alternatives

Instead of poking into the inner bowels of the installation package you are trying to automate, documentation from its author is often much safer. When that's missing, you can find a tool that helps you generate a response transform (much easier to use, but fallible), a tool that helps you explore the tables I described above (harder, but gives as complete an understanding as you can get), or you can create and examine a verbose log file created while installing the package with the settings you desire (middle of the road).

The log file will include all the properties and feature names you need to set on a command line, but probably will include several you do not need to set. Figuring out which is which can still be difficult.

#### End Result

In the end, you will end up with a command line including some of the following parts. I'm using italics to indicate the parts whose names or values I do not know; those should be substituted with correct values. I've also added parentheticals to explain what each part does; those should be omitted. I've broken the command line across multiple screen lines for clarity.

**msiexec /i *the.msi* /qn** (install *the.msi* silently)
  **ADDLOCAL="*desired,features,here*"** (select these features)
  **REMOVE="*undesired,features,here*"** (optional; explicilty unselect these features)
  ***SOMEPROP1*="*some value1*"** (specify the value of one or more properties)
  ***SOMEPROP2*="*some value2*"**
 
  ***SOMEPROP3*="*some value3*"** (specify more properties as necessary)

Note that property names are almost always going to be upper case and may include underscores. Feature names can be mixed case but will not include spaces. Property values can be anything, and must be quoted if they include spaces or other special characters.

If you plan to use this across multiple systems, note that differences in the target system can affect the correct command lines to use. This is relatively rare; when it happens, it's likely to be due to differing versions of Windows or differing availability of optional dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response !!!